# Hiding type parameter in a signature

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

Is there a reason why OCaml is not able to unroll intermediate parametrized types in a signature ?

For instance:

```
(* foo.ml *)
type 'a internal = Foo of 'a
type t = string internal
```

and:

```
(* foo.mli *)
type t = Foo of string
```

Give an error.

I guess this is releated to the fact that the memory representation can be different sometimes, but I was wondering if there is any deeper reason before submitting a bug report to the OCaml bug-tracker...

Comment: Seems to me the two types `t` are the same, but the two `Foo` constructors are not the same.  If this is right, it might not be about unrolling the parameterized type so much as the conflicting definitions of `Foo`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not a memory representation question. When matching a type declaration against a type signature, or more generally when checking if a declaration `t1` is less general than a declaration `t2`, the type-checker currently considers only those three cases:

- `t2` is an abstract type or type abbreviation
- `t1` and `t2` are both sum types
- `t1` and `t2` are both records

The other cases fail with an error. In your case, `t1` (the type being checked) is a type abbreviation, and `t2` (the specification) is a sum type. This fail with a type error.

See the source code: `type_declarations` in [typing/includemod.ml](http://caml.inria.fr/cgi-bin/viewvc.cgi/ocaml/trunk/typing/includecore.ml?revision=12397&view=markup#l202).

This is not a memory representation consideration as `foo.ml` would fail with this as well:

```
type u = Foo of string
type t = u
```

Perhaps this check could be refined. You should ask on the bugtracker.

*Edit*: it's not trivial to tell how far this check should be refined. It is not correct in general to expand abbreviations on the signature side when checking signature matching, for example the following should not be accepted:

```
module Test : sig
  type t = Foo
  type u = t (* to the outside, t and u would be equal *)
end = struct
  type t = Foo (* while internally they are different *)
  type u = Foo (* sum/records are generative/nominative *)
end
```

The other way around (an internal equality is hidden from the outside) is correct and already possible:

```
module Test : sig
  type t = Foo
  type u = Foo
end = struct
  type t = Foo
  type u = t = Foo
end;;

fun (x : Test.t) -> (x : Test.u);;
(* Error: This expression has type Test.t but an expression
   was expected of type Test.u *)
```

Now, memory representation also come into account when considering abbreviation expansion, as the dynamic semantics (memory representation choices) of the type system is not preserved by such expansions:

```
module Test : sig
  type r = { x : float; y : float; z : float } (* boxed float record *)
end = struct
  type 'a t = { x : 'a; y : 'a; z : 'a } (* polymorphic record *)
  type r = float t
end
```

Answer (score 5):

It can, as long as the types are *structural* types, e.g.:

```
type 'a t = 'a * int
type u = string t
```

will match

```
type u = string * int
```

However, variants (and records) are *nominal* types in OCaml. That is, every declaration of such a type introduces a fresh type name. And nominal type specifications in a signature can only be matched by nominal type declarations, and they have to have an equivalent definition. Neither is the case in your example, so it isn't accepted. (This is a subtle corner of OCaml. The fact that structural type aliases and nominal type definitions share the same syntax doesn't help.)

FWIW, you can also rebind nominal types:

```
type 'a t = Foo of 'a
type 'a u = 'a t = Foo of 'a
```

will match

```
type 'a u = Foo of 'a
```

But that doesn't allow you to change the structure or parameters either, so doesn't help your case.